# Identify which pages triggered Google Maps API loads

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to analyze which parts of the site has the most Google Maps API loads, since the total API load count is much higher than expected.

Is there any way to see a grouped count of which pages was the originator for a Google Maps API load?
I am using the Google Cloud Platform > Google Maps tool to see the usage data, but this tool is not very informative on a technical level.

Since all of the Map API loads should be triggered on a user interaction, I cannot simply cross reference page views with Map Loads. 
I am almost certain there is a page that loads the map preemptively, but it's very hard to identify by code audits alone, and it would be much easier to first analyze actual usage and then verify if the map is loaded at the correct time.

All my Google Map API keys are locked to the domains they should be used from, so external abuse is not the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using different API keys for each page, because you can filter the usage by API key, in this way, you can determine which page has the large amount of visits since each API key is dedicated for each page.

Comment: That's a good suggestion for working around this! I am amazed Google apparently doesn't have information like that available in a product used in this scale though.